# Php Error Reporting even when display error is on

Tags: php, error-reporting

I'm getting a problem with my php scripts. No error reporting is being made in spite that in my php.ini  that i've set display error everywhere

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL 
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL
```

Comment: A line starting with `;` is a *comment*. Where are the actual configuration directives set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use these:

```
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

With no `;` at the start of the line. That is a comment and just disables the directive.

*Edit:* To use runtime configuration, just add these two lines at the beginning of your php script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: I've set it but still getting the same problem

Comment: If you have changed php.ini file then you have to restart your Apache server first. These configuration can also be set in runtime in your php code -http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php. So you should check for that too.

Comment: Still same problem even when i restart apache