# Dropdown list displays no value

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a Book details form where we can insert the book details.
 One of the field in this form is "`Category_Id`". The value of this field is coming from database.
 So I want to display all the category id that is stored in a table name " **book_catagory** ".
 I have tried to write code which I have done it earlier also but here no values are displayed in the form. Please help me to find my mistake.
My code snippet is as follow:

```
<td>Enter Category ID: </td>
<td>
    <?php
        $select_query = "select Category_Id from book_catagory";
        $select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query);

        echo "<select name='category_id' id='category_id'>";

        while ($select_query_array = mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run)) {
            echo "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($select_query_array['Category_Id']) . "' >" .
 htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["Category_Id"]) . " </option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: What you get result in `print_r($select_query_array);`?

Comment: This code appears to have been written in the 19th century. Come on; modern code for modern times.

Comment: Great work @Vucko  - now it actually looks like he did actually do this work rather than copy paste this from another site. Infact this question/code has been asked over and over again in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839519/php-form-dropdown-containing-options-based-on-sql-data

Comment: And @Mi-Creativity credit too

Comment: @Vucko thanks for that.

Comment: what is the right table name.....catagoy or catagory??

Comment: @ShudhanshShekhar my table name is book_catagory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like this :

```
    <td>Enter Category ID: </td>
    <td>
        <?php
            $select_query = "select Category_Id from book_catagory";
            $select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query);

            echo "<select name='category_id' id='category_id'>";

            while ($select_query_array=mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run)) {
     ?>
<option value=' <?php echo htmlspecialchars($select_query_array['Category_Id']) ?>' >
    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($select_query_array['Category_Id']) ?></option>
            }
    <?php
            echo "</select>";
        ?>
    </td>
```

Also I would say that you should use mysqli. And you can also use mysql_fetch_asssoc if you need an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to establish the connection via the object orientated approach.This way to connect to database server is since PHP 5.5.0 deprecated.[1] Your query seems to be correct. You parse your SQL results with `mysql_fetch_array()`, which return a numeric and associated array.[2] If you prefer to parse your database result by associated attribute name only you should use the PHP method `mysql_fetch_assoc()`[3].

You can alter your code by following to fix your issue:

```
<td>Enter Category ID: </td>
<td>
    <?php
        $select_query = "select Category_Id from book_catagory";
        $select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query);

        echo "<select name='category_id' id='category_id'>";

        while ($select_query_array = mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run), MYSQL_NUM) {
            echo "<option value='".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array[0])."'>" .htmlspecialchars($select_query_array[0]) . " </option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
    ?>
</td>
```

References: 
[1] http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.summary.php 
[2] http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php 
[3] http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: issue remains the same. @Kevin

Comment: Did you have had send the sql statement direct in the database to check which results should been shown? Alternatively you can add an integer value to count while loops: `int i = 0; while() {} echo 'While loops:'.i;`

Comment: Changed my post above. Maybe alteration works for you?